# Хочу чтобы код выдавал в список все варианты расположений элементов из другого списка. Место задуманного результата выдает 24 None

Tags: python, случайные-числа

```
import random
index = [0, 1, 2, 3]
index_every = []
while len(index_every) < 24:
    b = random.shuffle(index)
    if b != index_every:
        index_every.append(b)
    b = 0
print(index_every)
```

Я нашел модуль itertools. Написал:

index_every = itertools.combinations(index, 4)

Выдает:

<itertools.combinations object at 0x00000207C292EE50>

Что нужно сделать чтобы выдавались комбинации?

Comment: и что ответила золотая рыбка?

Comment: Неправильно задал вопрос. Место всех случаев выдает 24 None.

Comment: Все варианты расположения: `list(itertools.permutations(index))`. А если исправлять ваш код с рандомом, то нужно заменить `if b != index_every` на `if index not in index_every`.